# React native compass angle issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

I have a compass that I created in react native. It has a couple of issues and I don't know how to best approach them.

Firstly, the arrow in the middle is hardcoded with top and left which seems to make it not responsive. I tried setting parent to relative and arrow to absolute.

Secondly, the angle doesn't stay consistent to the heading. Realistically, heading will fluctuate as the user moves the phone. Going anywhere from `0` to `360` in value.

The issue is that the angle needs to follow the heading. At `0`... they seem to be fine but if the heading is changed to 200... the angle should be facing towards `0` not `200`.

I tried to change the transform for arrow to this:

```
270 - heading - angle
```

But seems to be off sometimes, regardless

How can i go about solving this?

```
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(200);

  const updateHeading = (headingObject) => {
    const roundedHeading = Math.round(headingObject.trueHeading);
    setHeading(roundedHeading);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.angle}>Angle is: {angle}°</Text>
        <View style={styles.arrowContainer}>
          <Image
            source={require('./assets/arrow.png')}
            style={{
              width: width / 10,
              height: width / 10,
              left: '47%',
              top: 160,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              transform: [{ rotate: angle + 'deg' }],
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={styles.compassWrapper}>
        <Image
          source={require('./assets/compass_bg.png')}
          style={{
            height: width - 80,
            width: width,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            transform: [{ rotate: 270 - heading + 'deg' }],
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.dev/H-1WiF7It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is close. The arrow.png image is oriented already pointing "north", or up, but the compass_bg.png image is oriented with "north" pointing "east", or +90°. This image needs either -90° or +270° applied as a starting point ***and then*** the `heading` value added to it same as the arrow.

```
transform: [{ rotate: -90 + heading + 'deg' }],
```

Next is the issue of arrow positioning:

```
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [angle, setAngle] = useState(75);
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(200);

  const updateHeading = (headingObject) => {
    const roundedHeading = Math.round(headingObject.trueHeading);
    setHeading(roundedHeading);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      {
        Number.isInteger(angle) ? (
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.angle}>Angle is: {angle}°</Text>
            <View style={styles.arrowContainer}>
              <Image
                source={require('./assets/arrow.png')}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  width: width / 10,
                  height: width / 10,
                  left: '50%', // <-- center left/right
                  top: 160,
                  resizeMode: 'contain',
                  transform: [
                    { translateX: '-50%'}, // <-- center image horizontally
                    { translateY: '50%' }, // <-- center image vertically
                    { rotate: angle + 'deg' }
                  ],
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : ( null )
      }
      <View
        style={styles.compassWrapper}>
        <Image
          source={require('./assets/compass_bg.png')}
          style={{
            height: width - 80,
            width: width,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            transform: [{ rotate: -90 + heading + 'deg' }],
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

We can improve this however by co-locating the arrow and compass images together.

Example:

```
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [angle, setAngle] = useState(75);
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(200);

  const updateHeading = (headingObject) => {
    const roundedHeading = Math.round(headingObject.trueHeading);
    setHeading(roundedHeading);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      {Number.isInteger(angle) && (
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.angle}>Angle is: {angle}°</Text>
          <View style={styles.compassWrapper}>
            <Image
              source={require('./assets/arrow.png')}
              style={[styles.arrow, { transform: [{ rotate: angle + 'deg' }] }]}
            />
            <Image
              source={require('./assets/compass_bg.png')}
              style={[
                styles.compass_bg,
                { transform: [{ rotate: -90 + heading + 'deg' }] },
              ]}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  compassWrapper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  angle: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: height / 25,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  arrow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  compass_bg: {
    height: width - 80,
    width: width,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/react-native-compass-angle-issues

| Angle | Heading | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0° | 0° | [image] |
| 200° | 200° | [image] |
| 75° | 200° | [image] |

Comment: This makes the arrow always point towards North. However, I wanted to point towards the Angle. Lets say Angle is 43. I wanted arrow to always point towards 43 degrees no matter what the heading is

Comment: Also in typescript translateX and translateY expects a number not string. So the percentages don't work

Comment: @HeelMega So... you just want the compass face and arrow to operate independently? If Typescript typings are important can you include them in your post and snack? The string values for the transform appear to function just fine. I'm willing to bet it's typed for both.

Comment: Yes, the compass face and arrow should operate independently. Here is a snack with your new edited post: https://snack.expo.dev/Y0GQvyJ_8

I will look to create a snack with Typescript

Comment: @HeelMega Hmm, yeah I see [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms#decomposedmatrix-rotation-scalex-scaley-transformmatrix-translatex-translatey) where the "translate" properties are said to be of type number, but passing a sting with a percentage seems to totally work (*in the web at least*). The positioning part was extraneous to your question about the angles though, but I'll dig a bit more.

Comment: @HeelMega Actually, the `compassWrapper` is already centering content, so no positioning or translate rules are necessary.

Comment: Great. The only thing missing is angle orientation now

Comment: @HeelMega Can you clarify what you mean by "angle orientation"? Is that not the `angle` state driving the arrow?

Comment: So for example... i want to know the angle from x1, y1 coordinates to x2, y2 coordinates from my phone. Let's say we do the math and figure out what the angle is from it and that is 43 degrees. I can rotate my phone however I like so my bearing would change as my phone rotates BUT the angle still should be pointing to 43 on the compass no matter what the bearing is

Comment: @HeelMega Oh, I see, so you are just saying that you only need to implement a function similar to `updateHeading` that computes and updates the `angle` state value.

Comment: That is correct. I have the function that calculates the angle too but I just didn't add it into the snack because its not needed. We can test with hardcoded value for angle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246981/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-heelmega).

Comment: Turns out your second solution was correct of co-locating the arrow and compass images together. Thank you!

Comment: @HeelMega Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!